# How to run aws file on localhost

Tags: python, aws, flask

I'm new to Ubuntu and I installed `python-flask` and apache2 on my machine. I wish to run a python project that is presented in aws server. When I run the code it sucessfully runs on port 0.0.0.0:5000 but when I open it in a browser it shows `Unable to connect`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

> The address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate
>   an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target. … In the context of
>   servers, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine".

<sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)</sub>

Therefore use an other IP address or `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) to test your application locally.
To access your application from other hotsts in your network, check your ip address via

```
ip addr | awk '/inet / && ! /lo$/ {split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]}'
```

Comment: is there any other ways